# Need to take out the people who do not have a grade of "3"

Tags: database, mongodb

I have 4 documents in collection "load" where we have names of students and their grades for each subject. I need to get Names of student who do not have a grade of "3"

```
ved1=({subject: 'subject1', control: [{name: 'Name1', grade: 5}, {name: 'Name2', grade: 5}, 
{name: 'Name3', grade: 5}, {name: 'Name4', grade: 4},{name: 'Name5', grade: 4} ,{name: 'Name6', grade: 3},
{name: 'Name7', grade: 5},{name: 'Name8', grade: 5},{name: 'Name9', grade: 5},{name: 'Name10', grade: 4}]})
db.load.save(ved1)

ved2=({subject: 'subject2',  control: [{name: 'Name1', grade: 4}, {name: 'Name2', grade: 5}, 
{name: 'Name3', grade: 4}, {name: 'Name4', grade: 5},{name: 'Name5', grade: 4} ,{name: 'Name6', grade: 4},
{name: 'Name7', grade: 5},{name: 'Name8', grade: 4},{name: 'Name9', grade: 3},{name: 'Name10', grade: 5}]})
db.load.save(ved2)

ved3=({subject: 'subject3',  control: [{name: 'Name1', grade: 3}, {name: 'Name2', grade: 5}, 
{name: 'Name3', grade: 5}, {name: 'Name4', grade: 4},{name: 'Name5', grade: 4} ,{name: 'Name6', grade: 5},
{name: 'Name7', grade: 5},{name: 'Name8', grade: 5},{name: 'Name9', grade: 5},{name: 'Name10', grade: 4}]})
db.load.save(ved3)

ved4=({subject: 'subject4',  control: [{name: 'Name1', grade: 5}, {name: 'Name2', grade: 5}, 
{name: 'Name3', grade: 5}, {name: 'Name4', grade: 4},{name: 'Name5', grade: 4} ,{name: 'Name6', grade: 3},
{name: 'Name7', grade: 5},{name: 'Name8', grade: 5},{name: 'Name9', grade: 5},{name: 'Name10', grade: 4}]})
db.load.save(ved4)
```

i can get Min grade of each student, but goal is little different

`db.load.aggregate([{$unwind: "$control"},{$group: {_id: "$control.name", min_grade:  {$min: "$load.grade"}}} ,{$sort: { "min_grade": -1}}])`

Also tried to make this query but it doesn't work
`db.load.aggregate([{$unwind: "$control"},{$group: {_id: "$control.name", no_three: {$gt: ["$control.grade", 3]}}}])`

Help me to get Names of student who do not have a grade of "3", please

Answer (score 1):

Query

- for each student find the min-grade, and check if they have grade3
- if you want you can add a match and keep only those that dont have grade 3

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=626aba278b39bcf74dae276b)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$unwind": "$control"},
 {"$group": 
   {"_id": "$control.name",
    "min-grade": {"$min": "$control.grade"},
    "has-grade3": 
     {"$sum": {"$cond": [{"$eq": ["$control.grade", 3]}, 1, 0]}}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"has-grade3": {"$cond": [{"$gt": ["$has-grade3", 0]}, true, false]}}}])
```

Comment: good it helped, if works press the button on the left of the answer to mark it as solved, helps those that writes the answers, and other people to know which answer works or not, or if problem is solved or not.